# Why an average scoped function brings a relation when the query has any results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm have a problem with scope functions in Rails(4.2.7) Active Record models.

I have defined that scope function below to compute the average movie size and also a identically class method:

```
  scope :average_size, -> { average(:file_file_size) }

  def self.average_size_test
    average(:file_file_size)
  end
```

When the query match some records, the scope and class method works as expected:

```
2.2.4 :037 > Video.average_size
=> #<BigDecimal:1d483b0,'0.1790511428 57143E6',18(36)>
2.2.4 :038 > Video.average_size_test
=> #<BigDecimal:4f278b8,'0.1790511428 57143E6',18(36)>
```

However, when the query not match results, the class method and the scope method results are different:

```
2.2.4 :040 > Video.where(language: 'ch').average_size_test
 => nil 
2.2.4 :041 > Video.where(language: 'ch').average_size
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Why that behavior happens?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that behavior is the `scope chaining`. A scope always returns `ActiveRecord::Relation`, while [`average`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Calculations/average) call in your `average_size_test` method returns `nil` for no results.

Comment: However, the Rails official guide says "This is exactly the same as defining a class method, and which you use is a matter of personal preference:" http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes